# Native Camera returned opening error "Cannot Initialise Camera Connection" with Opencv/native Android

Tags: android, opencv, camera, android-ndk

I'm encountering a strange error while using the front facing camera on my Android Tablet (The back facing camera never has this problem). More and more frequently I encounter either a completely green video capture or, at startup,  my native code produces the following messages...

```
...E/OpenCV::camera﹕ ||libnative_camera_r4.1.1.so
...D/OpenCV::camera﹕ try to load library 'libnative_camera_r4.1.1.so'
...D/OpenCV::camera﹕ Loaded library 
...D/OpenCV_NativeCamera﹕ CameraHandler::initCameraConnect(0x5e904465, 1, 0x5b4cf430, 0x0)
...D/OpenCV_NativeCamera﹕ Connecting to CameraService v 2.3
...E/OpenCV_NativeCamera﹕ initCameraConnect: Unable to connect to CameraService
...E/OpenCV::camera﹕ CameraWrapperConnector::connectWrapper ERROR: the initializing function returned false
...E/OpenCV::camera﹕ Native_camera returned opening error: 6
```

I suspect the camera is possibly not being shut down properly, because sometimes it will work again after a reboot (but not always). Meanwhile, even if I launch any of the pre-installed camera apps on my tablet the camera still doesn't work (again, just the front facing camera).

Can anyone shed light on this? If the camera won't work after a reboot, is there something I can do to unlock/restore the camera if indeed that's the problem?

I'm using the r10c ndk with OpenCV-2.4.8.2-Tegra-sdk and developing in Android Studio with SDK Version 22. Meanwhile, my tablet is a Neo3do running Android 4.1.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If, after reboot, you sometimes cannot connect the default camera app to front camera, this is most likely a hardware problem.

Comment: My first thought was a hardware problem too. But with it sometimes working again after a reboot I was hoping there might be a software explanation. Sometimes on Linux for example, a resource can remain unopenable until an erroneous hidden .lock file is deleted. That couldn't be the case here?

Comment: No hidden files involved in android camera locking to the best of my knowledge.